# How to capture screenshot of tkinter window and store it to file?

Tags: python, tkinter, screenshot, keydown, pyautogui

I am trying to create a function that will screenshot specifically the tkinter window.

This is currently the best method I have found so far:

```
    def save():
        pyautogui.keyDown('alt')
        pyautogui.keyDown('printscreen')
        pyautogui.keyUp('printscreen')
        pyautogui.keyUp('alt')
        self.img = ImageGrab.grabclipboard()
        self.img.save('paste.jpg', 'JPEG')

self.dataSend = Button(main, text = "Send", command = save).grid(column = 1, row = 13, sticky = W)
```

Reason I am using `pyautogui.keyDown` and `Up` for `alt + screenshot` is because this click function print screens the application window only.

But sometimes when I click the button `Save` an error shows up:

```
    self.img.save('paste.jpg', 'JPEG')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'save'
```

Is there any other alternatives to this? And have a smoother way of screenshotting the tkinter window on click of a button and storing the jpg file?

Answer (score -1):

You should use [pyscreenshot](https://pypi.org/project/pyscreenshot/):

```
import pyscreenshot
pyscreenshot.grab().save('screenshot.png')
```

If you need to get part of screen, you can use that option:

```
im = pyscreenshot.grab(bbox=(10, 10, 510, 510))  # X1,Y1,X2,Y2
im.save('screenshot.png')
```

Or save from clipboard with use `ImageGrab` from [Pillow](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.0.x/reference/ImageGrab.html):

```
im = ImageGrab.grabclipboard()
im.save('screenshot.png')
```

It's works for me:

```
pyautogui.hotkey('alt', 'printscreen')
img = ImageGrab.grabclipboard()
img.save('screenshot.png')
```

And note `grabclipboard` only work for Windows and Mac OS

Comment: Hi this screenshots only full-screen

Comment: Its not same as 'Alt' 'PrintScreen'. The window can be anywhere on the screen, so this technique isn't ideal.

Comment: @HecticPython try save from clipboard after 'Alt' 'PrintScreen'.

Comment: `AttributeError: module 'pyscreenshot' has no attribute 'grabclipboard'`

Comment: @HecticPython sorry it was typo. May be should use ```pyautogui.hotkey('alt', 'printscreen')``` instead ```keyDown``` and ```keyUp```? Look at last update answer.